# CMake pkg_check_modules does not search the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, pkg-config

I am trying to compile a project that uses `CMake` and `pkg_check_modules` where I cannot get `pkg_check_modules` to find libraries located under `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

I believe the following example recreates the problem:

If I have `libtest.so` located in `/home/user/test/lib`, then given the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(
  TEST
  REQUIRED
  libtest
)
```

...and running it with:

```
cmake -DPKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=TRUE -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/test .
```

...results in the error:

```
No package 'libtest' found
```

I also tried running against `strace -v -f`, which does include an `access` attempt for `/home/user/test/lib/pkgconfig`, but logs nothing for `libtest`.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and CMake 3.5.1

Comment: Do  you have a file `/home/user/test/lib/pkgconfig/libtest.pc`? It is what `pkg_check_modules` is looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev. I was not aware of the .pc files. Updating the path to point to those worked. If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro `pkg_check_modules` is a wrapper around [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) utility, which searches `.pc` file and read it. The error

```
No package 'libtest' found
```

means that you have no `.pc` corresponded to the package, or CMake cannot find that file.

Comment: for my case, I do see the `.pc` file in `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig` but somehow CMake cannot find that file.  Any idea?

Comment: If you got the **same error message** (`No package 'FOO' found`) then it means CMake doesn't search `.pc` files under given directory. E.g. if you build the project for 32-bit platform, then `lib64` directories are not searched.